# A tricky question involving convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I'm struggling to find a title for this. Hopefully it can be edited subsequently.

Suppose $\sum_k s_k(x)$ converges to $S(x)$

Now suppose each $s_k(x)$ has a sequence $t_k^N(x)$ approaching it (as $N \to \infty$)

Can we say that $\sum_k{t_k^N(x)} \to S(x)$ as $N \to \infty$?

I'm pretty sure the answer is "not necessarily" and that uniform convergence is necessary.

Is this correct?

Comment: that $t_k^N(x) \to s_k(x)$ when $N \to \infty$ and $\sum_k s_k(x)$ exists doesn't mean that $\sum_k t_k^N(x) $ exists (you can easily find counter-examples) and $x$ is useless here

Comment: The Q is whether $\lim_{K\to \infty} \lim_{N\to \infty}$ $\sum_{i=1}^K T-{K,N}=$ $\lim_{N\to \infty}\lim{k\to \infty}T_{K,N}$ where  $T_{K,N}=\sum_{j=1}^Ks_J^N.$ Interchanging the order of limits  is often not valid. In this case  $\lim_{k\to \infty}T_{K,N}$ can fail to exist for any $ N.$

Answer (score 1):

A simple example where $\sum t_k^N(x)$ diverges and $\sum a_k(x)$ converges is $t_k^N(x) = x(1/k^2 + 1/N).$

As an example where both series converge and all limits exist, but you cannot interchange the limit and sum, let $t_k^N(x) = \frac1{N}e^{-k/N}$.

Note that

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \lim_{N \to \infty}\frac1{N}e^{-k/N} = 0,$$

but

$$\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{N}e^{-k/N} = \lim_{N \to \infty}\frac{1/N }{1 - e^{-1/N}} = 1.$$

Uniform convergence is a *sufficient* condition that permits the interchange, but it is not *necessary*.

To see that it is not necessary, consider the following counterexample:

$$t_1^N = \frac{1}{N}\left(1 - \frac{1}{N} \right); \,\,\, \,t_k^N =\frac{k}{N}\left(1 - \frac{1}{N} \right)^k - \frac{k-1}{N}\left(1 - \frac{1}{N} \right)^{k-1} \,\, \text{for }\,\, k = 2, 3, \ldots$$

Then

$$a_k = \lim_{N \to \infty}t_k^N = 0, \\ S_n^N = \sum_{k=1}^n t_k^N = \frac{n}{N}\left(1 - \frac{1}{N} \right)^n, \\ \sum_{k=1}^\infty t_k^N = \lim_{n \to \infty}S_n^N = 0,$$

and

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty t_k^N = 0 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lim_{N \to \infty} t_k^N.$$

However, $\sum t_k^N$ does not converge uniformly to $0$ for $N \in \mathbb{N}, $ since with $N = n$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}S_n^n = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)^n = e^{-1} \neq 0.$$

Comment: @P-I-: As seen from the counterexamples the interchange of sum and limit is not always permissible, as you suspected.  I also added an example to show that uniform convergence of the series is not a necessary condition to permit the interchange. Your last statement that uniform convergence is necessary should be corrected to sufficient. That uniform convergence is sufficient is, of course,  given by the well-known theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $t_k^N=1$ for $N\leq k$ and let $t_k^N=0$ when $N>k. $ Then $s_k=\lim_{N\to \infty}t_k^N=0. $ So $\sum_{k\in N}s_k=0. $ But for $n>N$ we have $\sum_{j=1}^nt_j^N=n-N. $ So $\sum_{j\in N}t_j^N=\infty $ for each $N.$